# How to specify resources for cluster in snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I am trying to run `snakemake` version `3.5.4` on my cluster, where jobs are partially defined by a common template build according [manual](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html#cluster-configuration) and also defined though rule-specific parameters. But for some reason cluster configuration is not expanding wildcards (and command does). When I run

```
snakemake data/genome.fa.gz.bwt -p --jobs 10 --cluster-config cluster.json --cluster "bsub -J "{rule}.{wildcards}" -q {cluster.queue} -n {threads} -M {resources.M} -R {cluster.one_host} -o {cluster.output} -e {cluster.error}"
```

`-J "{rule}.{wildcards}" -q {cluster.queue} -n {threads} -M {resources.M} -R {cluster.one_host}` expands as expected. But `-o {cluster.output} -e {cluster.error}` is replaced by literally `logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards}.out` and `logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards}.err`, i.e. there is no expansion in config file (the config file is attached bellow).

I am puzzled since exactly this lines are in the documentation. What am I doing wrong? Why `snakemake` is not expanding wildcards in the config file?

Here is my `cluster.json`

```
{
    "__default__" :
    {
        "queue"    : "bgee",
        "one_host" : "\"span[hosts=1]\"",
        "name"      : "{rule}.{wildcards}",
        "output"    : "logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards}.out",
        "error"     : "logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards}.err"
    },
}
```

Here is relevant part of `Snakefile` :

```
rule index_reference :
        threads: 1
        resources: M=20000000
        input : "data/{reference}/genome.fa.gz"
        output : "data/{reference}/genome.fa.gz.bwt"
        shell : "scripts/index_genome.sh {input}"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature was added in version 3.6.0. Look at [release notes](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/history.html).

`{wildcards}` normally expands to a something that looks vaguely like a dictionary. In other words, something like `key1=value1,key2=value2`. Whether you really want to use that as a log file name is up to you.

Let's use a very contrived example to demonstrate this. Here is the `Snakefile`:

```
rule all:
    input: "input1.human.txt"

rule blah:
    output: "{sample}.{reference}.txt"
    shell: "touch {output}"
```

I'm using your `cluster.json`, so with that let's use a contrived cluster submission program:

```
snakemake --cluster-config cluster.json --cluster "echo 'rule.wildcards: {rule}.{wildcards} cluster: {cluster} -o {cluster.output} -e {cluster.error} -n {cluster.name}' >> log && " --jobs 1
```

If you run that and look in `log`, you can see that `{rule}` is expanded as expected, `{wildcards}` is expanded to `sample=input1,reference=human`. The `output` and `error` parts from `cluster.json` are expanded correctly for me. Below are the contents of `log`:

```
rule.wildcards: blah.sample=input1,reference=human cluster: one_host="span[hosts=1]",output=logs/cluster/blah.sample=input1,reference=human.out,name=blah.sample=input1,reference=human,queue=bgee,error=logs/cluster/blah.sample=input1,reference=human.err -o logs/cluster/blah.sample=input1,reference=human.out -e logs/cluster/blah.sample=input1,reference=human.err -n blah.sample=input1,reference=human
```

I'm not a big fan of using `{wildcards}` in paths unless you're doing a parameter sweep, but to each their own. Note that the above results are from snakemake-4.3.1.

Answer (score 3):

The solutions are either, upgrade `snakemake` or just take all wildcards out of `cluster.json` file and write them directly to snakemake execution command :

```
snakemake -p --jobs 10 --cluster-config cluster.json --cluster "bsub -J "{rule}" -q {cluster.queue} -n {threads} -M {resources.M} -R {cluster.one_host} -o {"logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards}.out" -e "logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards}.err""
```

However, I ended up instead of using of json config file in writing a simple bash wrapper `snakemake_cluster.sh` that remembers the execution command for me in more readable format :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

snakemake $@ -p --jobs 10 --cluster "bsub \
-J {rule} \
-q bgee \
-n {threads} \
-M {resources.M} \
-R \"span[hosts=1]\" \
-o logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards}.out \
-e logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards}.err"
```

Edit : All spaces after `--cluster` command got to be escaped, otherwise it would add arguments to `snakemake` not to `bsub`.

Edit 2 : `$@` means all arguments, therefore it can be either targets, flags or combinations (targets got to be specified first). So, `snakemake_cluster.sh my_file` builds `my_file`, `snakemake_cluster.sh --quiet` builds default target quietly, and `snakemake_cluster.sh my_file --quiet` builds `my_file` quietly.

Answer (score 1):

As of the most recent snakemake (v5.10.0) the recommended way of defining resources is through a [profile](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#profiles).

It seems you are trying to submit a job on an LSF cluster system - there is a snakemake [profile for LSF](https://github.com/Snakemake-Profiles/snakemake-lsf) to save you having to do this work yourself.

It reduces your snakemake submission to something like

```sh
snakemake --profile "lsf"
```

Comment: Luckily I don't have to deal with `lsf` anymore, but thanks anyway, I will take a look at this feature.